# Eclipse CDT can't build - not sure what's wrong (console included)

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-cdt

I'm now going to give c++ a try to see what this language have to offer. I'm having some trouble setting it all up though. I have downloaded Eclipse CDT and followed this guide : http://www.dcs.vein.hu/bertok/oktatas/cpp_by_eclipse/eclipse_for_cpp_on_windows.html#Install_gdb

I am using Windows 7 64bit.

I have never installed a compiler before, and I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. It gives me an "Launch failed. no binary found" error when I try to run my program. However there is no binaries folder. I have tried building, it loads for a while, but nothing really happens.

Any idea what to do? I am completely new at c++ so please be patient and let me know if there's anything I am missing :)

The console in eclipse says the following:

Build of configuration Debug for project Test2 **

Internal Builder is used for build ** cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi /nologo /Fospam.obj ..\spam.cpp Internal Builder: Cannot run program "cl" (in directory "C:\cppworkspace\Test2\Debug"): CreateProcess error=2, Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet Error: Program "cl" is not found in PATH

PATH=[C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec\MyWinLocker 3\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec\MyWinLocker 3\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\MinGW\bin] Build error occurred, build is stopped Time consumed: 156 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple enough, Eclipse can't find your compiler.

On the lengthy PATH that is quoted I don't see 'c:\MinGW\bin' so I'm guessing you had problems with step 4 under section install MinGW.

Having said all that I don't think Eclipse is a very good environment for developing C++ and I don't think MinGW is a particularly good compiler. I'd seriously recommend you take a look at Visual C++ 2010 Express, which you can download from here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

**EDIT**

OK now I do see 'c:\MinGW\bin', so apologies for that. I think the likely explanation is that you have selected the wrong 'tool chain'. Eclipse thinks you want to build with Visual C++ but you have downloaded MinGW. But really get Visual C++ 2010 Express and forget about Eclipse, it's much easier.

Comment: Actually I already got Visual studio 2010, as I usually work with the .net platform. I just felt like trying eclipse again (used it for making java applications a few years ago). But I guess everything is a lot easier in 2010, It's just so heavy - Eclipse is more light. But that's only a problem when I'm on this laptop. I'll try selecting another tool chain, if that doesn't work I'll try out Visual studio.

Comment: The most lightweight solution would be to use the command line. You can use MinGW that way and this would also be a good test to see if your MinGW installation is OK.

Comment: @john _"But really get Visual C++ 2010 Express and forget about Eclipse, it's much easier."_ I'd be willing to bet there are about a million folks who would laugh at that statement, including me. IntelliSense is beyond terrible. Visual Studio is good for debugging, and that's about the extent of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you will compile with Eclipse CDT + MingGW Compiler you should use the MinGW toolchain

[MingW Toolchain](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/760/toolchian.jpg)

If you want use Eclipse + Microsoft C++ compiler, need change for "Microsoft Visual C++" toolchain and put in PATH

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin

or whatever you have because CL program is there...