# Eclipse C++ Print to Console

Tags: c++, console, std, eclipse-cdt, cout

I am trying to print to console with C++, I was told that this code works, but I got a bunch of errors, so I need to know how to print to console with c++, and I also need to know why it doesn't work for me when others say it works.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: When I launch it, eclipse tells me the binary is not found, but what binary, it never created a bin folder, do I create a bin folder myself, or do I configure the build path, what do I do?

Edit again: I realized I haven't built my project yet, I will get back soon.
When I build it, it tells me:
Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[G:\ProgramData\myworkspace\C++\Project\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\WINDOWS\System32]

Edit: I have downloaded the microsoft visual c++ compiler, but I don't know which folder, it apparently installed into C:\WINDOWS, and there are some stuff in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studios 14.0. Problem is, I do not know which folder I should set up the environment variable with, and if I should remove an environment variable.

If you could help me, that would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `C++` is installed on your machine? If so How about the paths? Add the errors you get.

Comment: We are going to need to see your errors, since this compiles fine

Comment: Notice that (unlike Visual Studio) Eclipse CDT does not came with compilers or libraries. You need to install all that stuff separately.

Comment: My guess is that your program is compiling and running just fine.  What is happening is that the program runs so fast that you don't see the output on the monitor although it is there for about 1/1000th of a second.  Add the statement 'system("pause");' just before the return 0; statement.  That will keep your output on the screen.  What errors did you get with this code?????

Comment: I do not think so Dr t. The OP explicity said it gets some error. I quote @VTT  answer. Have you installed the compiler? if you are under Linux, open the terminal (ctrl+T) and write  g++ -v. If it complains, than you need a C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes, I have been able to run many apps that use C based languages, such as C++, I think that it is preinstalled on my computer.

Comment: "binary is not found" means that build failed and there is nothing to launch. You should check out build log.

Comment: The compiler output should list the path to the executable file for you.  Compile it again and look for the path in the build results.  Then navigate the directory to that folder and that file and run it.

Comment: Please, copy and paste your whole build log

Comment: Where do I get my build log? Is it just a file path?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had first installed Eclipse in order to write C++. As others have pointed out in the comments, the problem was that no C++ compiler was provided for the IDE.

So, basically, you need to choose one compiler, install it to your machine (don't forget to set up environment variables, so Eclipse can "see" it) and then select that compiler in the IDE. To do that, go to project properties (accessible in Eclipse by right clicking the project name in the project explorer and selecting Properties) -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor and these set the "Current toolchain" and "Current builder" fields to match your chosen compiler.

**Notes:**

- Don't forget to set up the compiler for both Release and Debug versions (and any others you might have).
- I found it easy to get the MinGW GCC compiler working following this YouTube tutorial -> [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSAY50OL_J4&t=285s), and that one should be fine if you're just starting to learn C++, though you can of course use any other compatible compiler if you want (and there may by all means be better compilers out there, I'm just saying this one was pretty easy to install for me).

**Edit:**

- This SO question seems relevant -> [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130552/eclipse-cdt-cant-build-not-sure-whats-wrong-console-included?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know which folder I should set up the environment variables with, it apparently installed into C:\WINDOWS, there are some Microsoft Visual Studio folders in C:\Program Files (x86) too. If you could help, that would be appreciate, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I honestly have no idea how to set up Visual C++ Compiler with Eclipse. Can I ask why you don't want to use Visual Studio? (Since you're on Windows anyway and it's probably the best IDE to use with Visual C++ Compiler.)

Comment: I do want to use the Microsoft visual studio, I just don't know which environment variables to set up, I tried many compilers that were installed on my laptop, but either they simply don't have the "make" program, or I am setting it up wrong, right now the only way I can compile C++ is by using the command prompt of Microsoft visual studios, but I want to do it straight from eclipse.